# Dojo/Dijit - create and istantiate a custom widget only using javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, dojo

I want to create a simple custom DIJIT widget that contains a simple button ( and later I will add some other stuff ).

I've created the file filterWidget.js (in the root) :

```
dojo.provide("custom.FilterWidget");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.declare("custom.FilterWidget", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    constructor: function() {

    },
    postCreate: function() {
        // Show a Dojo tooltip on the user name node.
        new Button({
            label: "test"
        }).placeAt(this.containerNode);
    }
});
```

In the "main" application I try to instantiate the "FilterWidget" by a button click.

```
require([
    "dijit/form/Select",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "filterWidget",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, Button, ContentPane, FilterWidget) {


    new Button({
        id: "add",
        label: "Add",
        onClick: function()
        {
            new FilterWidget().placeAt("filterlist");

        }
    }).placeAt("filtri");

    new ContentPane({
        id: "filterlist",
        style:"width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    }).placeAt("filtri");


});
```

When I load the page, I can see the "Add" button, clicking on it the Chrom debugger says : 
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (referring to FilterWidget, I suppose).

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: Is the widget created? Is the placeAt method available? Try debugging in the onClick method.

Comment: I see a few potential problems.  In your widget definition you create a "Button" instance but don't define it as required.  I'd also look to post or examine the exact source statement and/or call stack so we know which statement is causing the error.  Posting your code like this is along the lines of "Here is my book manuscript, it contains a typo ... can you find it?".  You have more information at your disposal to help potential responders but have not yet posted it.